# How $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ can be equal to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$?

Tags: roots, fractions

How $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ can be equal to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$?

I got answer $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, but the real answer is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Anyway, calculator for both answers return same numbers.

Comment: What if you multiply by $1 = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: Commander, you have to learn basic maths elsewhere you will be stuck with this questions for years.

Comment: @Karl: There is absolutely no requirement on this site that questions must not be about "basic maths". We welcome questions at all levels!

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. Yes, I am learning math right now. When I went to school I didn't paid attention to my teacher and etc, missed a lot of lessons, but now I am back on track and I want to master math.

Comment: The major question is: How is $\frac{\sqrt 2}2$ the "real" answer and $\frac1{\sqrt 2}$ is not? After all, both are correct - but sometimes it is customary to avoid square roots in the denominator. I guess this point becomes moot at least if one is urged to write $\frac{\sqrt{17+3x^4+\cos x}}{17+3x^4+\cos x}$ instead of $\frac1{17+3x^4+\cos x}$ ...

Comment: @Henning Makholm Please read my post before reprimanding me. I did not say so, but I reminded the OP that he will have to do this  elsewhere he will have to ask for such things always here and *this* will be not good for him.

Comment: @Karl: And you're wrong about that. It is completely fine for him to ask the question here. It is simply not correct that he has to go "elsewhere" to learn basic before he can ask here!

Comment: @Henning Makholm. Please try to understand what I said: I did not say that he has to go *elsewhere*, elsewhere has also the meaning of *otherwise*. I said: *You have to study basics maths otherwise  you will have to ask for such things always here.*  Is the difference in the meaning of *elsewhere* as I used it and how you understood it now clear to you? Or have I to explain it in more detail?

Comment: @Karl: Let me qoute what you wrote, verbatim: `you have to learn basic maths elsewhere`. That is wrong, and trying to claim that you wrote something else will not make what you actually wrote right.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: Please read the complete sentence: *you have to learn basic maths elsewhere you will be stuck with this questions for years*. This meanswhat I said.

Comment: @Karl: And even if you had written what you now claim you wrote, it is still quite rude to tell the OP "you have to learn the thing you're asking about" -- that's exactly what he's trying to do by asking the question! By what right do you insinuate that he _doesn't_ want to learn what he's asking about? If he didn't, why would he even ask?

Comment: @Henning Makholm Apparently you want to have an argument with me, but I don't want to have one with you. No need for continuing.

Comment: @Karl: Your spat with Henning is simply a misunderstanding! "Elsewhere" certainly does not mean the same as "otherwise": it means, unambiguously, "in another place", i.e. not here on math.stackexchange. Probably you were thinking of "else"; but "otherwise" is more correct here.

Comment: @TonyK   Ok, I got it wrong, I apologize, no need for further quarrel. Sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing we tend to like to do when dealing with this stuff is have the denominator of fractionish things as a plain number, as much as possible.  To do this, we'll multiply both top and bottom by something that will cancel out any radicals in the bottom.
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
This even works for more complicated stuff.
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{5-3}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Comment: I would argue that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is no less and probably more simple than $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, but most middle- and high-school math teachers inexplicably disagree.

Comment: Of the three common formats, I'd pick $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$ over $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ over $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  Halving is a lot easier to think at than dividing by an irrational number.

Comment: I don't know what you think is complicated about dividing by an irrational number, but it ultimately doesn't matter.

Answer (score 10):

Since $2=\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{2}$ you have that $$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 4):

Let's square both of them:
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}^2 &= \frac{1}{2}, \text{ while} \\
\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}^2}{2^2} \\ 
&=\frac{2}{4} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} 
\end{align}

So they're both positive numbers, and their squares are the same, so they must be the same.

Answer (score 3):

The number $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is defined to be the number such that, when you multiply it by $\sqrt{2}$, you get $1$. Symbolically, it is the solution to $x\cdot \sqrt{2}=1$. That's how division works - it's the inverse of multiplication. What is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}2\cdot \sqrt{2}$? Why, it's $\frac{2}2=1$ - so it must be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, as it satisfies the definition of division for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=2^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{2^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2^1}=2^{\frac{1}{2}-1}=2^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Answer (score 1):

The sqrt(2)/2 turns into sqrt(2/4) when the two is squared and put under the square root which simplified is sqrt(1/2).